# How to center view below CollapsingToolbarLayout inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

When having a CollapsingToolbarLayout inside CoordinatorLayout you need to use app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" so the view below the toolbar moves down the height of the toolbar, but in that case this view below the toolbar goes beyond the window itself on the bottom, thus if I want to center something in it between the toolbar and the bottom of the screen it's not really possible?

Here is my code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/generic_toolbar_collapsing" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/list_view_empty_string"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here a screenshot from the layout editor:

[image]

The selected view on the picture is the LinearLayout, you can see how the dots go beyond the bottom window line, so the text is centered inside the view, but not centered relative to the toolbar and the bottom of the window, is it possible to achieve this?